# Stacked cards using jQuery - sequencing animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate a stack of cards. I borrowed some code off of the web that was a three-card stack and everything worked fine, but I'd like to add more cards to the stack. The jQuery is using 'first' 'next' and 'last' which I think is limiting it to 3x cards.

If you click 'next step' a few times in the codepen here you can see that it works for cards 1 and 2, but then when it moves to card 3 the final card also moves: https://codepen.io/chrisjcastle93/pen/rNMJNLr

What I'm trying to achieve is for the left and right margin on the 3rd card to be 0 when Step 3 is active (with 4 maintaining its margin) and then the 4th (and final card) to do the same when that card is selected.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="section2play">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="inner-container">   
                                <div class="card inactive-1" style="height: 8px; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;"></div>
                                <div class="card inactive-2" style="height: 8px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;"></div>
                                <div class="card inactive-3" style="height: 8px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;"></div>       
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="content active" style="opacity: 1; right: 10%;">
                                        <h1>Step 1</h1>
                                        <p>Make perfectly hot homemade coffee. Carefully pour into coffee cup. <i class="em em-coffee"></i></p>
                                        <a class="button" href="#">Next step →</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h1>Step 2</h1>
                                        <p>Trip. Spill all over the place.</p>
                                        <a class="button" href="#">Next step →</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h1>Step 3</h1>
                                        <p>Repeat.</p>
                                        <a class="button" href="#">Next step →</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h1>Step 4</h1>
                                        <p>Repeat.</p>
                                        <a class="button" href="#">Next step →</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#section2play body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#section2play .container {
    margin: 4em auto;
}

#section2play .inner-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 360px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
}

#section2play .content {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 2em;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#section2play .active {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}

#section2play .card {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e5eef2; 
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2em 0;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .3s ease;
    /* box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35); */
}

#section2play a {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 2px;
        left: 0;
        width: 0%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid $aqua;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    &:hover:before {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#section2play").ready(function() {


var content = $('.content');
var currentItem = content.filter('.active');
var inactive1 = $('.inactive-1');
var inactive2 = $('.inactive-2');
var inactive3 = $('.inactive-3');

$('.button').click(function() {
  
    currentItem.removeClass('active');

    if (currentItem.is(content.last())) {
        currentItem = content.first().addClass('active');
        currentItem.css({'right': '10%', 'opacity': '1'});
        inactive1.animate({height: '8px', marginLeft:'30px', marginRight:'30px'}, 100);
        inactive2.animate({height: '8px', marginLeft:'20px', marginRight:'20px'}, 100);
        inactive3.animate({height: '8px', marginLeft:'10px', marginRight:'10px'}, 100);
      
    } else if (currentItem.is(content.first())) {
        currentItem.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
        currentItem = currentItem.next().addClass('active');
        inactive3.animate({height: '0', marginLeft:'0px', marginRight:'0px'}, 100);
      
    } else {
        currentItem = currentItem.next().addClass('active');
        inactive1.animate({height: '0', marginLeft:'0px', marginRight:'0px'}, 100);
        inactive2.animate({height: '0', marginLeft:'0px', marginRight:'0px'}, 100);
        inactive3.animate({height: '0', marginLeft:'0px', marginRight:'0px'}, 100);
    } 
});
```